# while connecting to remote mysql(from local) I'm getting this error

Tags: mysql, express, phpmyadmin

while connecting to remote mysql(from local) I'm getting this error. here I'm using express and mysql and phpmyadmin in remote with host details

```
Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'geonewso_sud'@'68.243.15.80' (using password: YES)
    at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (C:\IFF\Personal\my-api\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Handshake.ErrorPacket (C:\IFF\Personal\my-api\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Handshake.js:123:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\IFF\Personal\my-api\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (C:\IFF\Personal\my-api\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (C:\IFF\Personal\my-api\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (C:\IFF\Personal\my-api\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\IFF\Personal\my-api\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:88:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\IFF\Personal\my-api\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:283:12)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (C:\IFF\Personal\my-api\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (C:\IFF\Personal\my-api\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (C:\IFF\Personal\my-api\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:116:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\IFF\Personal\my-api\server.js:19:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:741:12)
  code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
  errno: 1045,
  sqlMessage:
   'Access denied for user \'geonewso_sud\'@\'68.243.15.80\' (using password: YES)',
  sqlState: '28000',
  fatal: true }
```

Comment: Did  you check the privileges for geonewso_sud? can he access your table

Comment: yes I had all privileges.

Comment: 'geonewso_sud'@'68.243.15.80' for his specofoc ip has all the privileges? To be honest, any Sql database that is accecible over inzternt makes me nervous and i recomend to use a vpn and restrict the connectio to a local ip range.

Comment: That definitely doesn't look like a phpMyAdmin error message. Can you tell us what exactly you're doing when you get the error? Do you see the login page first or does this come before you even try to enter your username and password? What is the value of the auth_type directive in the configuration file `config.inc.php`?